# SoundCloud: how to stop playing when hash change

Tags: ajax, soundcloud

I'm using ajax page switching method with SoundCloud script.

How to stop playing music when the user leaves the page with SoundCloud container?

I've found these stokes:

```
// stop all players, might be useful, before replacing the player dynamically
  $.scPlayer.stopAll = function() {
    $('.sc-player.playing a.sc-pause').click();
  };
```

Currently I call initialization `$(".sc-player").scPlayer();` inside `.load` function, but where do I need the put the code which will stop playing audio before any page switching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add event listener `window.onhashchange = stopAll;`

and definition of stopAll() will be

`stopAll = function() {
    $('.sc-player.playing a.sc-pause').click();
  };`

Comment: cucko, thank you!!! Now it works!

Sorry, I cannot add you a reputation because I have no rights to do it. Anyway, thanks!