# SoundCloud: how to stop background playing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, jquery, soundcloud

I'm using ajax page switching method with SoundCloud script.  How to stop playing music when the user leaves the page with SoundCloud container? What I must to do? Please help!

Here is a page where I have a custom SC player: http://lightmuzikrecords.com/mastering/#!examples/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SoundCloud Widget API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) which gives you programmatic control over the playback. Look at the [Widget playground](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html) for demos.

Comment: I've found an answer but I don't understand it. (here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378715/soundcloud-how-to-stop-playing-when-hash-change)

I really beginner in html/java.. Can you tell me how I must combine those code?

All of my attempts was failed..